# JS not working in popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
chrome.app.window.create('testcb.html', {
'bounds': {
  'width': 1240,
  'height': 720
    }
  });
});
```

That opens

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cb.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/design.css"/>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
```

The java script does not work whatsoever. I'm entirely new at making extensions/apps. And full explanation is needed.

Comment: Are you developing a Chrome App or a Chrome Extension ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I tried both. So far, The app opens a nice window that I like but the JS barely works, and <a> for html doesnt work. 

The extension doesnt do what I want it to. So I assume I need to be focusing on an app for a game and not an extension 

What happens: The app window opens with the webpage I need it to. The JS game has an adder that works After clicking a few of the buttons that are made in JS there are tabs that you click on to view things. Those tabs do not work in the popup window And this line of HTML doesnt work in the window either
http://pastebin.com/EQZYuSvW (text limit)

Comment: You can see whats happening here
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/E2bLrvL.png)

Comment: I really can't guess what might be going wrong. Check if you get any errors in the console log. Or post more code, so we can take a deeper look into it. But, please, when posting code, keep in mind: **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**;.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this post is quite old, but I figure some input might help for anyone having troubles with this still.

There are actually a few different reasons this could be happening.

This could possibly be due to security measures that are built into your browser (Chrome in this case) that block Javascript scripts from loading/running.

Another possibility may be that there are errors in your JS. A quick and easy way to check is to use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

If you are still not getting anywhere something that usually helps me is to put the JS code directly inside a script tag in the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        // JS code here
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/design.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully something here can give you some results, or a direction to head in!

Comment: Chrome extension popups cannot have inline JS.